# Qual comando no Mysql que mata o processo caso uma query demorar mais que 20s para executar?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Galera gostaria de saber algum comando de configuração no mysql, que mate o processo caso a query demorar mais que 30 segundos para retornar algum resultado existe ? como ?

Answer (score 1):

Para listar os processos da base e só executar o seguinte comando:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST
```

Será exibida a lista dos processos que estão ativos.

Para matar o processo basta verificar o ID do mesmo e digitar:

```
KILL [numero_do_processo]
```

Ex:

```
mysql> KILL 23435
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode configurar um *timeout*.

Isso pode ser feito no servidor, na própria conexão, ou ainda somente para a operação que deseja executar.

Configure um *timeout* de 30 segundos e, caso não haja resposta da query nesse intervalo, um erro será retornado. Daí você pode tratar este erro (na sua aplicação, por exemplo).